# Understanding the val declaration syntax for type Some in scala

Tags: scala, syntax

While going through Spray.io examples library I came across this declaration of `val` in FileUploadHandler example of routing app.

`val Some(HttpHeaders.Content-Type(ContentType(multipart: MultipartMediaType, _))) = header[HttpHeaders.Content-Type]`

As per my understanding the variable declaration goes as `val <identifier> = ...`

Please help in understanding this paradigm of syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Scala language spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html): Value definitions can alternatively have a pattern as left-hand side. Watch out for `PatDef` in the document.

Section "Patterns in Value Definitions" of [Daniel Westheide's Blog](http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/05/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-3-patterns-everywhere.html) gives a nice overview on the usage.

Answer (score 2):

`val` is a bit more complex than just an assignment operator.

A definition

```
val p = e
```

where `p` is not just a variable name, is expanded to

```
val x = e match { case p => x }
```

Take a loot at the simplest example:

```
val Some(s) = Some(5)
```

As a result, `s` would be equal 5.

In your example `header[HttpHeaders.Content-Type]` is matched against Some(...).

Comment: Then again we've got `s` as an identifier . In my example the `Some` surrounds a complex library call.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for extractors/mattern matching in scala, please see http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/112.

You need a simple form of it, take a look at this snippet:

```
scala> val Some(t) = Some("Hello")
t: String = Hello
```